# Centos 7 Samba php:apache Permission Denied when moving file with Docker container after moving to :z volume from samba share

Tags: docker, centos, samba

First, let me say that chmod 777 does not even work for this (though I know that would not be the correct solution).

Here's the situation:  I have a mail server receiving mail.  On that server there is a cronjob that runs a .sh script that moves the mail files to a samba share.  A separate app server (which is where I'm having the problem) also has a cronjob that runs a .sh script that moves those mail files from the share:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(ls -A /samba/reports)" ]; then
mv /samba/reports/* /home/adam/dmarc/reports/mail
chown adam:adam /home/adam/dmarc/reports/mail/*
chmod 664 /home/adam/dmarc/reports/mail/*
fi
```

This all seems to work just fine.  Note, the cronjob is run as root (it's root's crontab).  Also, the 'reports' directory is mounted as a volume inside a php:apache Docker container (-./reports:/var/www/reports:z).  The files are there and available to read within the container.  However, when I use php (invoked from a script, not apache) I am denied permission to rename/move the files.  However, if I cat each file to an identical file with a different name:

```
cat theProblemFile > noProblem
```

....then it works fine.  Owner/group and permissions are exactly the same for both.

Is there something about the file having been moved from a Samba share that makes it different?  What is going on here?  Also, in the matter of getting the files from the mail server to the app server, is there an industry-standard/best-practice/preferred way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You moved files (without the `-Z` option) instead of copying them, so they carry their original SELinux contexts instead of the appropriate contexts for their destination.

When you created a new file, it had the correct SELinux context already.

You can use `restorecon` to fix the SELinux contexts on the affected files, for example:

```
restorecon -rv <directory>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you recommend a good way to learn what I should/need to know about SELinux?  I thought it might have to do with SELinux, but getfacl didn't show anything different.

Comment: @AdamWinter You might try the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/index) for a start.